Why do I need to explicitly set <input>.value to make the user-showing text in an input change?
In the following component (range.svelte) why do I have to do inputElement.value = valueToSet; at line 24 when the input element value is bound to value (<input value={value}...)? Why isn't the assignment to value just before at line 27 sufficient?
Some more context: the idea is for the user not to be able to enter a number outside of the range in the "number" type input.
<script lang="ts">
    import { RangeSlider } from '@skeletonlabs/skeleton';

    export let value: number;
    export let suffix: string;
    export let min: number;
    export let max: number;

    export let name: string;
    export let step: number = 1;

    let clazz: string = ""

    export {clazz as class};

    function onInputChanged(event: Event): void {
        const inputElement = event.target;

        const newValue = inputElement.value;

        const valueToSet = computeValueToSet(newValue);

        value = valueToSet
        inputElement.value = valueToSet;
    }

    function computeValueToSet(newValue: string): number {
        if (newValue === "") {
            return value;
        }

        const newInt = parseInt(newValue, 10);

        const isInRange = min <= newInt && newInt <= max;
        if (!isInRange) {
            return value;
        }

        return newInt;
    }
</script>

<div class="flex flex-row gap-4 {clazz}" {...$$restProps}>
    <RangeSlider name={name} class="basis-3/4" bind:value {min} {max} {step}>
        <span class="flex justify-between">
            <span class="text-xs">{min}{suffix}</span>
            <span class="text-xs">{max}{suffix}</span>
        </span>
    </RangeSlider>
    <span class="basis-1/4 flex flex-row gap-1 items-center">
        <input
            class="input text-sm w-auto"
            type="number"
            value={value}
            on:input={onInputChanged}
            {min}
            {max}
            {step}
        />
        <span>{suffix}</span>
    </span>
</div>



Svelte updates the DOM on change. If the new value is outside the valid range, you effectively set value to value, hence the state is determined to have not changed and no update is performed.
You could force an update by first invalidating the variable via a completely different value, e.g.
value = null;
value = valueToSet;

(This might only work with the reactivity model of Svelte 3/4.)

Is there any especially svelte-y way to do this? What would you do in that case?

I am not a huge fan of coercing input, it can be awkward to work with and just tends to get in the way. I would use native form validation, if min/max are set, the submission will automatically be blocked and a validation error will be shown.

If you're looking for a Svelty way of doing it, you can just bind:value and sanitize it with a reactively called function to clamp it. I found clamping with a simple reactive statement like $: value = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, value)) locks it in the min  value if min is larger than 0 because whenever value changes it automatically clamps it. So we can create a function that respects the input logic to prevent premature clamping and call it reactively
function clampInput(newValue:number) {
    // get how many digits `min` and `value` have
    const minLength = Math.floor(min).toString().length
    const valueLength = Math.floor(value)?.toString().length || 0
    
    // don't clamp while `value` has less digits than `min`,
    // also allows for backspace without bugging
    if (valueLength < minLength) return

    //reassign value to a clamp between the `min` and `max` props
    value = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, newValue))
}

//call `clampInput()` whenever `value` changes
$: clampInput(value)

This way your whole component looks like this:
<script lang="ts">
    import { RangeSlider } from '@skeletonlabs/skeleton';

    export let suffix: string = "suffix";
    export let min: number = 43;
    export let max: number = 900;
    export let value: number;

    export let name: string;
    export let step: number = 1;

    let clazz: string = ""

    export {clazz as class};

    function clampInput(newValue:number) {

        const minLength = Math.floor(min).toString().length
        const valueLength = Math.floor(value)?.toString().length || 0
        
        if (valueLength < minLength) return

        value = Math.min(max, Math.max(min, newValue))
    }

    $: clampInput(value)
</script>

<div class="flex flex-row gap-4 {clazz}" {...$$restProps}>
    <RangeSlider name={name} class="basis-3/4" bind:value {min} {max} {step}>
        <span class="flex justify-between">
            <span class="text-xs">{min}{suffix}</span>
            <span class="text-xs">{max}{suffix}</span>
        </span>
    </RangeSlider>
    <span class="basis-1/4 flex flex-row gap-1 items-center">
        <input
            class="input text-sm w-auto"
            type="number"
            bind:value
            {min}
            {max}
            {step}
        />
        <span>{suffix}</span>
    </span>
</div>

